# Pinescript syntax to pseudocode

Tags: pine-script

So I'm trying to understand thos lines and coming from C# and Python I'm having a hard time to understand this syntax :

```
rv = b < c*a

sl = rv == 1 and high > y and close < y and open < y

ss = rv == 1 and low < x and close > x and open > x 

li = sl ? y : ss ? x : (x+y)/2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `rv = b < c*a`  - result is a bool variable `rv` which value (`true` or `false`) depends of the expression `b < c*a`.
2. `sl = rv == 1 and high > y and close < y and open < y` result is a bool variable, expression can be simplified as

   `sl = b1 and b2 and b3 and b4` where:

   `b1 = rv == 1`  (true or false)

   `b2 = high > y` (true or false)

   `b3 = close < y` (true or false)

   `b4 = open < y` (true or false)
3. same
4. is a ternary operator https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator

Comment: so for sl if all b1,b2,b3 and b4 are true it should return true and if one of em is false it should return false, right ?

Comment: Yep that was the case thanks for the precious insights mate